# How to prevent animation from running when clicking on another button when div is already visible

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm going crazy because I can't see where this logic fails.

I have this directive logic:

```
movies.directive('detailsBox', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var current, 
          previous;

      element.on('click', function() {

        if (!current) {
          current = $(this).data('index');
        }
        else {
          previous = current;
          current = $(this).data('index');
        }

        if (current === previous || previous === undefined) {

          // Add a delay so the images 
          // have a chance to load the first time it runs
          $timeout(function() {
            $('.details-box').slideToggle(function() {
              $('.details-box .toggle').fadeToggle();
            });
          }, 300);
        }

      });

    }
  }
}]);
```

And three buttons:

```
<button data-details-box data-index="1">1</button>
<button data-details-box data-index="2">2</button>
<button data-details-box data-index="3">3</button>
```

Each one of these buttons will toggle a div with some content:

```
<div class="details-box">
  <div class="toggle">Some content</div>
</div>
```

If I click on button nr 1, and then button nr 2 or 3, no animation should run since the details box is already visible.

If I click on button nr 1 and then button nr 1 again, the animation should run, therefore closing the details box.

The problem is that the animation is running when I click on button nr 1 and then button nr 2 or 3. Which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here I think.  First... the directives don't know about the previous and apply variables in the other directives.  You need to link them to the common scope.

```
scope: {
  current: '=current',
  previous: '='
},
```

And in your html...

```
<button data-details-box data-index="1" current="current" previous="previous">1</button>
<button data-details-box data-index="2" current="current" previous="previous">2</button>
<button data-details-box data-index="3" current="current" previous="previous">3</button>
```

Secondly, I believe you need to use scope.$apply() in your element.on call.

```
scope.$apply(scope.previous = scope.current);
```

Here's a working plunker that does what I think you want.  I'm not sure how you wanted the initial conditions...

http://plnkr.co/edit/bu34bNSe6yHXCA9SQEUC?p=preview

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I can't get this to work in my scenario, despite having the exact same code. I think it's because I have my buttons in different scopes, since I'm using an ng-repeat on the button parent.

Comment: I had to introduce a 3rd variable called "closed", or the fade in toggle would not work with your current logic. And you were right that I had to bind it to the scope instead of local variables since they would just reset every time the function ran. Didn't realize it before I stepped over the code in the console. I will accept your answer since it guided me. Hop hop cheerios.